# БД для многопользовательского приложения

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Пытаюсь сделать многопользовательское андроид приложение. Пользователь проходит регистрацию. Затем переходит на активность. заполняет данные. и их может быть несколько объектов. Так вот, мне нужно сделать вложенную бд. Так как я даже не любитель, а скорее новичок, то я не понимаю как это реализовать. Простой пример без вложенной бд реализовать могу, а такое нет. 
Примерная бд, которая должна получиться представлена ниже. 
Как создать класс???

```
{
    "userinfo":
     {
      "dm"://допустим email пользователя
       {
        "kosm": 
        {
           "p1":
               {
                "name":"mascara",
                "kategory":"eyes",
                "srok":"12.06.2025",
               },

           "p2":
               {
                "name":"mascara",
                "kategory":"eyes",
                "srok":"19.06.2024",
               }

        }
        "wishes":
        {
            "w1":
            {
                "name":"maskara prosto super"
            },
            "w2":
            {
                "name":"maskara prosto ok"
            }
        }
      },

      "buba":
       {
        "kosm": 
        {
           "p1":
               {
                "name":"mascara",
                "kategory":"eyes",
                "srok":"12.06.2025",
               },

           "p2":
               {
                "name":"mascara",
                "kategory":"eyes",
                "srok":"19.06.2024",
               }

        }
        "wishes":
        {
            "w1":
            {
                "name":"maskara prosto super"
            },
            "w2":
            {
                "name":"maskara prosto ok"
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

ну например:

```
{ 
"dfjdfd"://idпользователя 
{ 
"name":"dfgdfgfg", 
"kategory":"gdfgfg",
}, 
"dfdgfjdfd"://idпользователя 
{ 
"name":"dfgdfgfg", 
"kategory":"gdfgfg",
}, 
}
```

класс

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String kategory;
    public User() {
    }
    public User(String name, String kategory) {
        this.name = name;
        this.kategory= kategory;
    }
}
```

а мне нужно чтобы как в вопросе для каждого пользователя создалось 2 объекта в которых еще есть данные.

Comment: Объясните как вы делаете "без вложенной БД". В таком виде вопрос непонятен.

Comment: пояснения давайте не в комментариях, а изменяя сам текст вопроса.